# Compare the count of two tables in informatica

Tags: oracle, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have to table one is error and the other one is success (by id)
I need to compare the count of rows in the two tables group by id.

Output : the count of rows of the id 1 in the error table , the count of rows for same id in the success table then I need to compare both counts.

How can I do it in informatica?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use two aggregators - one for success pipeline and one for errors. Both should have

1. group by id
2. create a new column called count = count(*)

Then use a Joiner to join these pipelines. Join on ID.

Then use an expression to compare columns from count_succcess and count_errors.

Whole mapping should look like this

```
---> AGG_Success(grp by id, count = count_success)| 
                                                  |--> JNR join on id --> link all columns to compare count_success and count_errors
---> AGG_Errors(grp by id, count = count_errors)  |
```

Comment: Fist of all thank you for your answer, Then I can get that value in the workflow and based on it I send an email ? If yes how?

Comment: if you have to send email with success count and failure count, i think, you need to create two sessions - one will output number of success rows, another will output number of failure rows. based on number of rows output you can email.